How to Generate QR Image to crystal report dynamically without add new blob field manually?
Can I add a QR image to a Crystal Report dynamically without adding a new column to the
dataset and dragging it to the report? I retrieve the URL from the database, and based on
that, I display the image from S3 in a blob field.
I need to generate the blob field dynamically in Crystal Reports without adding a new
column (e.g., QRIMG11) and dragging it to the report. My goal is to add and display the QR
image in Crystal Reports dynamically based on the database URL I retrieve, and then display
the image returned from S3 for Column QRIMG11 Without add column Manually and drag it to
crystal report .
Is this possible in Crystal Reports?
   var ds = db.GET_UNIFIED_GOVS(P_LICN_CIVIL_ID, P_LICN_CENTRAL_NO);

    var P_DATA_CUR = ds.Tables["P_DATA_CUR"];

    // check dynamic qr filling 
    int numberOfQRCodes = P_DATA_CUR.Rows.Count; // Get the number of rows (QR codes)
    DataTable qrParamsTable = new DataTable(); // This will hold all QR images

    // Create columns for each QR code image
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQRCodes; i++)
    {
        qrParamsTable.Columns.Add($"QRIMG{i + 1}", typeof(byte[])); // Add column for each QR image
    }

    // Create a single row
    DataRow qrParamsRow = qrParamsTable.NewRow();

    // Loop through each row in the DataTable to fill the single row
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQRCodes; i++)
    {
        string qrObjectKey = P_DATA_CUR.Rows[i]["FILE_NAME"].ToString();

        // Get the image bytes from S3 using your existing method
        var imageBytes = new AwsFile() { objectKey = qrObjectKey }.GetImageBytesS3();

        // Set the value in the single row for the corresponding column
        qrParamsRow[$"QRIMG{i + 1}"] = imageBytes;
    }

    // Add the filled row to the DataTable
    qrParamsTable.Rows.Add(qrParamsRow);

  




    eReg_Crystal.Rpt.RptGET_UNIFIED_GOVS_Test cr = new Rpt.RptGET_UNIFIED_GOVS_Test();


    cr.SetDataSource(P_DATA_CUR);

    cr.Database.Tables["QrParams"].SetDataSource(qrParamsTable);

as image below :

Updated post
suppose I add picture 1 to crystal report so how to generate images dynamically based on code above csharp to generate images dynamically .
updated post
Can you give answer for me
what Changes I will do on c# to make dynamic image generation
which section it will put this image report footer or page footer or what
How to generate loop for image using dummy image
How to pass URL from c# to crystal report step by step
please I need help

can you give me more details please  how to insert dummy image to crystal report please

suppose i add picture 1 to crystal report so how to generate images dynamically based on code above c#

Yes, it is possible.

Insert a dummy image (it will be dynamically replaced).
Right click the image, 'Format Graphic', Picture tab
Use the button to enter a dynamic expression for 'Graphic Location'
set the expression to the url returning the QR code.
Refresh the report

note: this would work with http url. If you must use https, you might need to use a UFL (user function library) to get around a limitation.

can you give me more details please how to insert dummy image to crystal report please

Use the menu option of:
Insert, Picture...

so how to modify code above to fill color dynamically

There is no need for special code. You just need an expression that returns the URL resulting in the desired dynamic image.  Here is the relevant portion of the online help on this topic:


To make a static OLE object dynamic

1.Right-click the static OLE object that you inserted, and choose Format Graphic from the shortcut menu. 

Note
You begin the process of making a static OLE object dynamic by inserting the object into your report as usual. This object becomes the default object. If Crystal Reports cannot find the dynamic reference to the object, it uses the default object instead. 

2. In the Format Editor window, click the Picture tab, and then click the (Conditional Formula) button adjacent to the Graphic Location label. 

3.In the Formula Workshop, create the path to your static OLE object. For example, if your path is stored in a database field, add that field to the formula. 

4.Click Save and close to return to the Format Editor.

5.(Optional) In the Picture tab, select the Use Original URL check-box to skip the URL encoding check. This is sometimes necessary when your URL contains certain special characters (such as “%3d”) that are already encoded (to for instance “=”), while the URL destination expects the original special characters.

6.Click OK to return to your report.

7. Click  (Refresh) to update the reference link to your static OLE object. 



